# select new column as null string in spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hiveql

I am attempting to generate a column of null values in spark, NOT a null datatype though.

So

```
sqlContext.sql("select null as newcol from db.table")
```

Will not work, as it will set newcol datatype to be null.

```
sqlContext.sql("select cast(null as newcol as string) from db.table")
```

Will not work because it will make all values "null" as the 4 character string representation.

How can I accomplish this?

The end goal is write this to a csv, which does not support the null column type and I need the actual values in the dataframe to be null and not empty strings.

Answer (score 9):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
select cast(null as string) as newcol from db.table
```

The expression is `cast(null as string)` -- this is just any old expression and could be much more complicated.  The column alias is provided using `as newcol`, which goes after the expression.

It is just a coincidence that `as` is begin used twice (for different things) in the definition of `newcol`.